# Advertisement loading failing

Tags: android, admob

We tried implementing admob in our application and some what we succeeded in it. But the problem is we are unable to maintain its consistency of the ads. Which means we are not getting it all the time.**No network issues, no crashes**. Please advise if some one have the same problem.

We are getting a response like

```
12-08 17:12:30.836: I/Ads(32502): No fill from ad server. 
12-08 17:12:30.851: W/Ads(32502): Failed to load ad: 3


 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view_header"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_header" />

       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();   
       mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: what is your refresh rate for admob ads? like 30 seconds or 60 seconds for next add to appear on AdView?

Answer (score 1):

`No fill from ad server.` is an expected message. It means that you requested an ad but that none were available for you at this particular time.

The best way to ensure you have a constant fill is to use mediation and include about 3 ad networks in your mediation list. That way if one does not have an ad, the next will be asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ad size issue. 
This is code working in my case for banner ad, try and let me know:

```
<TableLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableLayout>
```

This snippet from onCreate() main activity

```
    TableRow TR = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.TR);
    AdView   adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        .build();
    TR.addView(adView);
    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when admob server doesnot return ads from server usuallu happen in development mode .your code is correct if you use testdeviceid it will shown you test ads.this works well when app is live on google play

Answer (score -1):

You need to set refresh rate.

**As per the new sdk**

```
AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```